# How can I explicitly include entities in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I want to create a schema on my users. Here is my directory structure.

```
Users
-- collections.js
-- helpers.js
Players
-- collections.js
-- forms.js
```

However, when I try to include something from `Players/collections.js` in `Users/collections.js`, it says that it is not defined.

```
Meteor.users.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  // irrelevent stuff up here
  "profiles.player": {
    type: PlayerSchema,  // playerschema is defined in Players/collections.js
    optional: true
  }
}));
```

I consistently get the error code `ReferenceError: PlayerSchema is not defined`.

Is there a way to explicitly include certain entities in other files with meteor?

Comment: Using a package approach?

Comment: does it have to use a package approach, or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a project global.
   In your `/lib/config/_namespace.js` add the line: `G = {}`;
   This will be your ONLY file that doesn't `"use strict"`.
2. Now save your schemas to the global object:
   `G.PlayerSchema = new SimpleSchema(...`
3. Now reference it: `type: G.PlayerSchema`

For things like Collections, Schemas, utility functions, constants, and reactive dictionaries, this is a nice approach without having to package all the things.